# If I turn off notifications in the Page settings, will it turn off notifications for all page admins or just me?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am the Admin for a Facebook page.
However, organizationally I am not directly responsible for that page.
I sit on the board of the parent organization.
My being an administrator of that page is primarily for continuity management and bus-factor.

As such I don't want to really get any (or at least as many) notifications from that page.
So I am looking at turning its notification settings down.

However, I am worried that if I do, it will turn the settings down for all administrators of the page.
Which would be bad.
It seems unlikely that it would have been designed that way,
but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the notification setting will only effect you.
Not the other admins.

From [Facebook Support](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10155114914513849):

> When you change your notification settings for a Page you help manage, the notification settings of others who help manage the Page won't be affected.

Answer (score 2):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/172901342767609/?ref=u2u):

> When you change your notification settings for a Page you help manage, the notification settings of others who help manage the Page won't be affected. Others who work on the Page will still get notifications about the Page based on the settings they've chosen.
>
> To change your notification settings for a Page:
>
> 1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page
> 2. Click **Notifications** in the left column
> 3. Edit your notification settings